# Is there a way to do an "INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in Zend Framework 1.5?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, insert-update

I would like to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in Zend Framework 1.5, is this possible?

Example

```
INSERT INTO sometable (...)
VALUES (...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I worked for Zend and specifically worked on Zend_Db quite a bit.

No, there is no API support for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.  For this case, you must simply use `query()` and form the complete SQL statement yourself.

I do not recommend interpolating values into the SQL as harvejs shows.  Use query parameters.

Edit: You can avoid repeating the parameters by using `VALUES()` expressions.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (id, col2, col3) VALUES (:id, :col2, :col3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(col2), col3 = VALUES(col3)";

$values = array("id"=>1, "col2"=>327, "col3"=>"active");
```

Comment: Yes that is what I had done as well, I was really wondering if there was a method of Zend_Db_... that provides that functionality so maybe instead of using $db->insert() we can use $db->insertOrUpdate() ... just an idea.

Comment: No, there is no such method in Zend_Db.  The goal of the ZF product was always to provide simple solutions to the 80% most common cases.

Comment: You can extend it and add this feature easily ;)

Comment: Yes of course, but another goal was to avoid making special methods for proprietary SQL features for any brand of database.

Comment: Minor nitpick: you should use quotes around array keys, otherwise PHP will try to evaluate them as constants.

Comment: The array keys need to be of the form ':id', not 'id' else you end up with a columns not matching error from Zend.

Comment: Great solution. I am using this in ZF3.

Answer (score 6):

As a sidebar, you can simplify the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause and reduce the amount of processing your script needs to do by using `VALUES()`:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), col2 = VALUES(col2), col3 = VALUES(col3)';
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for more information.

Answer (score 5):

@Bill Karwin: great solutions! But it would be greater if to use named placeholders (":id", ":col1", …) instead of questions signs. Than you wouldn’n need to duplicate values by array_marge. Also if to use "SET" syntax of "INSERT" instead of "VALUES", the code gets simplier to be generated automatically for any set of fields.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO sometable SET id = :id, col2 = :col2, col3 = :col3
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = :id, col2 = :col2, col3 = :col3';
```

Comment: I believe that depends on the adapter you are using

Answer (score 4):

```
$arrayData = array('column1' => value1, 'column2' => value2, ...)

class Model_Db_Abstract extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name;
    protected $_primaryKey;

    public function insertOrUpdate($arrayData)
    {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `'. $this->_name.'` ('.implode(',',array_keys($arrayData)).') VALUES ('.implode(',',array_fill(1, count($arrayData), '?')).') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.implode(' = ?,',array_keys($arrayData)).' = ?';
        return $this->getAdapter()->query($query,array_merge(array_values($arrayData),array_values($arrayData)));
    }

}
```

**USAGE:**

eg. Model_Db_Contractors.php

```
class Model_Db_Contractors extends Model_Db_Abstract 
{

    protected $_name = 'contractors';
    protected $_primaryKey = 'contractor_id';

    ...
}
```

IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
 public function saveAction()
 {
  $contractorModel = new Model_Db_Contractors();
  $aPost = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

  /* some filtering, checking, etc */

  $contractorModel->insertOrUpdate($aPost);
 }
}
```

Comment: not sure why `array_merge(array_values($arrayData),array_values($arrayData))` but `array_values($arrayData)` will suffice

Comment: Good question, I don't remember why I put it there.

Comment: It is required for correct SQL query to bind second part of query (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... = ?) with array values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
REPLACE INTO sometable SET field ='value'.....
```

This will update if exists or just insert if not. This is a part of the standard mysql api.

Comment: No, it will not. Replace removes any existing matching row and inserts a new one. This will result in undesired behaviour, if you do not insert all values. Example: you have a table with a `time_created`. If you use update without setting the value, it will stay the same from when you created the row. If you use `REPLACE`, the row will be removed, a new will be inserted and `time_created` will be set to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Pawel's Answer to support separate insert and update data, and also supports Zend Db Expressions

```
  class Model_Db_Abstract extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {
        protected $_name;
        protected $_primaryKey;

        public function insertOrUpdate($arrayData)
        {
            $insertDataValuesForQuery = [];
            $queryParams = [];
            foreach ($insertData as $key => $value) {
                if (gettype($value) == "object") {
                    array_push($insertDataValuesForQuery, $value->__toString());
                    continue;
                }
                array_push($insertDataValuesForQuery, "?");
                array_push($queryParams, $value);
            }

            $updateDataValuesForQuery = [];
            foreach ($updateData as $key => $value) {
                if (gettype($value) == "object") {
                    array_push($updateDataValuesForQuery, $key . " = " . $value->__toString());
                    continue;
                }
                array_push($updateDataValuesForQuery, $key . " = ?");
                array_push($queryParams, $value);
            }

            $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->_name . ' (' . implode(',', array_keys($insertData)) . ') VALUES (' . implode(',', $insertDataValuesForQuery) . ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . implode(' , ', $updateDataValuesForQuery);
            return $this->getAdapter()->query($query, $queryParams);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -8):

you can simply do something like this:

set unique index on your id

and then

```
try {
   do insert here
} catch (Exception $e) {
   do update here
}
```

Comment: You can do that. It could be a working solution. But it is quite inefficient. That's why people are down-voting it.